# Can't get insertion control in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've searched all over the web, and my code seems to be nearly identical to everything out there, but I can't get my UITableView editing to work for inserting a row.  When I click the edit button, all of my existing rows get the delete control, but I get no additional row for insertion.  I'm pulling my hair out for what seems like it should be a simple thing.  What am I missing?

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [categoryTV setEditing: editing animated:animated];

    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[appDelegate appCategories] count] inSection:0];

    [self.categoryTV beginUpdates];
        if (editing) {
            [categoryTV insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        } else {
            [categoryTV deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];          
        }
    [self.categoryTV endUpdates];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 ...

    if (indexPath.row >= [[appDelegate appCategories] count])
        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"New Category", @"NewCategoryCellText");
    else
        cell.textLabel.text = [[[appDelegate appCategories] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] detailValue];


    ....

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.editing) {
        return [[appDelegate appCategories] count] + 1;
    } else {
        return [[appDelegate appCategories] count];
    }
}
```

As noted, I forgot to include my version of the suggested method, now shown below.  Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [[appDelegate appCategories] count]) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the following delegate method to assign an editing style:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

Obviously you will only return that for the cell you want to have an insert control.  Otherwise, you will need to return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had implemented a version of the method you suggested, and edited my question to include my version.

Comment: Are you still seeing just the delete control?

Answer (score 1):

I saw similar behavior in my `UITableView`, and the problem was that my `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method returned `NO` for the insertion control row.

Answer (score 1):

set `tableview` editing property YES

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    .......
    self.tableView.editing = YES;   //set editing property of tableview
    .......
}
```

> **editing** -  A Boolean value that determines whether the table view is in editing mode.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> **@property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing**
>
> **Discussion**
>
> When the value of this property is YES, the table view is in editing
>   mode: The cells of the table might show an insertion or deletion
>   control on the left side of each cell and a reordering control on the
>   right side, depending on how the cell is configured. (See
>   UITableViewCell Class Reference for details.) Tapping a control causes
>   the table view to invoke the data source method
>   `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:.`
>   **The default value is NO.**

then return that cell in which you want to have an insert control

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```